# External Antenna for ESP32-S2-DevKitM-1U

Tags: rf, antenna, esp32

For starters, I'm new to electrical engineering, especially rf applications, so I apologize in advance for anything dumb I say.

I currently have an ESP32-S2-DevKitM-1U, and am looking for an external antenna.

The documentation for this board is here:
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/hw-reference/esp32s2/user-guide-devkitm-1-v1.html

And the datasheet is here:
https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s2-mini-1_esp32-s2-mini-1u_datasheet_en.pdf

Looking at the datasheet, the external antenna connector is compatible with the following:

- W.FL Series connector from Hirose
- MHF III connector from I-PEX
- AMMC connector from Amphenol

However, I've been unable to find an antenna with these connectors. I've looked at various manufacturers and suppliers, including Mouser, Digikey, Newark, Farnell, Allied, Arrow, and Molex. I've also looked at the creators of these connectors themselves, Hirose, I-Pex, and Amphenol. Any antenna I've found with the right connector isn't fit for the 2.4Ghz range, which is what I need for wifi. The best I can find is an adapter between one of these compatible connectors and a common connector such as SMA.

Additionally, through my search for an antenna, I've learned about the existence of impedance, radiation patterns, resistance, gain, etc. I have only a slight idea of what these indicate, and have no idea what kind of characteristics I need.

To be more specific with what I am using this for, I intend to use the ESP32-S2-DevKitM-1U with the external antenna to connect to another device (laptop or phone) via wifi at some distance away (Perhaps around 50m? Is this range even possible with my setup?). Both devices would be at ground level, outside.

So, to summarize my main question: What kind of antenna do I need, and where can I find it?

Alternatively, where can I go to learn more about this subject matter, so that I at least sorta know what I'm doing?